# Difficulty Importing GASP Using Script

Tags: python, gasp

Using interpreter mode, `from gasp import *` runs, but when I place it in a script it doesn't. I'm copying this straight from chapter 4 of [How to Think Like a Computer Scientist: Learning with Python](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch04.html) (under heading 4.11. GASP).

Script:

```
from gasp import *

begin_graphics()

Circle((200, 200), 60)
Line((100, 400), (580, 200))
Box((400, 350), 120, 100)

update_when('key_pressed')
end_graphics()
```

Terminal:

```
ben@ubuntu:~$ python '/home/ben/Documents/Python/gasp.py' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ben/Documents/Python/gasp.py", line 1, in <module>
from gasp import *
File "/home/ben/Documents/Python/gasp.py", line 3, in <module>
begin_graphics()
NameError: name 'begin_graphics' is not defined
```

Comment: +1 for including the full traceback on your first question without being asked, and so actually giving us enough info to debug your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your script. You're hiding the real `gasp` module:

```
ben@ubuntu:~$ python '/home/ben/Documents/Python/gasp.py'
```

When you

```
from gasp import *
```

it's trying to `import` itself because you called it `gasp.py`.

Answer (score 0):

> Renaming the script does not solve the problem.
>
> ```
> ben@ubuntu:~$ python '/home/ben/Documents/Python/gasptest.py' 
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/ben/Documents/Python/gasptest.py", line 1, in <module>
> from gasp import *
> File "/home/ben/Documents/Python/gasp.py", line 3, in <module>
> NameError: name 'begin_graphics' is not defined
> ```

You included "/home/ben/Documents/Python/gasp.py" again. Delete this copy :)